# Referencing forign keys between schemas withSchema()

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have to use `withSchema()` to specify my schema name as creating contraints whilst specifying the schema name in the createTable arg (`.createTable("test1.user"...`) breaks the SQL to create the constraint. For instance the below would cause error

```js
    .createTable("test1.user", (t) => {
      t.uuid("id").primary().defaultTo(knex.raw("uuid_generate_v4()"));
      t.string("mongo_id");
      t.string("username");
    })
```

error:

`migration failed with error: alter table "test1"."user" add constraint "test1"."user_pkey" primary key ("id") - syntax error at or near "."`

And so I use `withSchema()` and the table is created fine, like so:

```js
.createTable("user", (t) => {
      t.uuid("id").primary().defaultTo(knex.raw("uuid_generate_v4()"));
      t.string("mongo_id");
      t.string("username");
    });
   .withSchema("test1")
```

However I also want to create foreign keys between schemas but also avoid the constraint issue mentioned above so I create my second table like so:

```js
  .createTable("profile", (t) => {
    t.uuid("id").primary().defaultTo(knex.raw("uuid_generate_v4()"));
    t.string("name");
    t.integer("user_id").unsigned();
    t.foreign("user_id").references("id").inTable("test1.user");
  })
  .withSchema("test2");
```

however I get the following error:

`migration failed with error: alter table "test2"."profile" add constraint "profile_user_id_foreign" foreign key ("user_id") references "test1"."user" ("id") - relation "test1.user" does not exist`

It seems I am stuck between two issues, and I cannot create constraints AND reference foreign keys between schemas. Is there a work around I am missing, short of writing raw statements and therefore making the use of `knex` completely redundant?

Who migration script below:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .raw("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test1")
    .raw("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test2")
    .raw('DROP EXTENSION "uuid-ossp"')
    .raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"')
    .createTable("user", (t) => {
      t.uuid("id").primary().defaultTo(knex.raw("uuid_generate_v4()"));
      t.string("mongo_id");
      t.string("username");
    })
    .withSchema("test1")
    .createTable("profile", (t) => {
      t.uuid("id").primary().defaultTo(knex.raw("uuid_generate_v4()"));
      t.string("name");
      t.integer("user_id").unsigned();
      t.foreign("user_id").references("id").inTable("test1.user");
    })
    .withSchema("test2");
};

exports.down = function (knex) {};
```

### Edit:

For the time being I have seperated each schema into its own migration scripts. One script builds the tables, a second script then goes in to add the foreign key references. For instacne:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .raw("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test")
    .withSchema("test")
    .createTable("profile", (t) => {
      t.uuid("id").primary().defaultTo(knex.raw("uuid_generate_v4()"));
      t.string("name");
      t.uuid("user_id").unsigned();
    });
};
exports.down = function (knex) {};
```

and then adds the foreign keys:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable("test.profile", (t) => {
    t.foreign("user_id").references("id").inTable("test2.user");
  });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact 2 errors. After some fiddling it appears that the createTable() function is impacted by withSchema(), while inTable() is not.

so something like the following worked for me

```js
.withSchema("test")
.createTable("profile", (t) => {
    t.uuid("id").primary().defaultTo(knex.raw("uuid_generate_v4()"));
    ...
    t.integer("user_id").references("id").inTable("test2.user");
      
});
```